# Upload Gitlab CI artifacts to a storage outside Gitlab

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab

The build artifact size is more than Gitlab CI allowed limit. So, I wish to upload them to a location outside Gitlab and use them in test stage. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you talking about the docker image size ?
If so you could host your own docker registry and docker tag and docker push to it in your pipeline (and reuse it later)

If it is another kind of custom image, you could send it via FTP or SFTP to a remote server and then retrieve it later (still through FTP or SFTP)